# How to implement Admob Interstitial Ad in android studio - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, admob, interstitial

**I am a beginner and I need help implementing Admob Interstitial Ad in the android studio using Kotlin. Sorry for my question, Appreciate it if you can show me step by step so I can learn the process and do it myself every other time. Thanks in advance.**

```html
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val one_Page: TextView = findViewById(R.id.one_Page)
        val three_Page: TextView = findViewById(R.id.three_Page)

   

        one_Page.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, PageActivity2::class.java)
            // start your next activity
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        three_Page.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, PageActivity2::class.java)
            // start your next activity
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: This maybe helpful  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynOqwzD21cs

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you are missing a few steps to get it right, to do that please follow these steps:

Note: I will use sample ids to load demo ads, you need to make sure it's worked then think about replacing the sample ids with real ids

1: Setup Admob dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
```

2: Add snippet code to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the `<application>` tag

```
<!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
<!-- Replace sample id if you have a real id from AdMob project - pattern ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy --> 
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

3: Initialize Admob and load an ad:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
  private final var TAG = 'MainActivity'
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      // Initialize Admob
      MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
      var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
      // ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 is a sample interstial id. 
      InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
          Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
          mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
          Log.d(TAG, 'Ad was loaded.')
          mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
      })
    }
}
```

4: Add the FullScreenContentCallback below `InterstitialAd.load`:

```
mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
  override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    Log.d(TAG, 'Ad was dismissed.')
  }

  override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
    Log.d(TAG, 'Ad failed to show.')
  }

  override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
    Log.d(TAG, 'Ad showed fullscreen content.')
    mInterstitialAd = null;
  }
}
```

6: Add showFullAd to MainActivity and call `showFullAd` in the activity where you want to show it

```
fun showFullAd(){
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
      mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
    } else {
      Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
    }
}
```

See more:

- [Get Started with Admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)
- [Implement Interstitial ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#kotlin explains how to request interstitial ads. Your code above created a `mInterstitialAd` variable but needs to still:

1. Load an ad
2. Show the ad at a natural stopping point in your app

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My issue is that I have tried the process but did not get it right. I need a step by step if you can help with the code I posted in my question above.